# How to tell where my Deep Links are being shared?

Tags: java, android, mobile-application, deep-linking

Deep linking's picked up popularity recently and I'm hoping to understand them a lot better sooner than later.

I've configured my app for deep linking and can open it from a deep link (testing on a local environment).

However, I can't know any information about /where/ the app was opened... or can I?

For example, if my users install my app, and they share a deep link on Facebook... I can't necessarily "force" them to include any parameters for tracking or analytics purposes!

So in this situation... I'm wondering, how can I know the page they shared it on? I want to get this data. Or is it just impossible? Or, as a last resort, will I have to just "guess" by say, checking what activity was switched out of before my app's activity was launched? (If it is possible...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can, you have two options. You can either build it yourself, or use a tool that does this. [Branch.io](http://branch.io) is one option.

If you want to build yourself, you need to do the following:

- Generate a link, and have some data in your servers associated with that link. E.g. https://mylink.com/abcd = a link posted on Facebook
- When someone clicks, get their IP address, and then redirect them to your app
- Upon app open, send IP address, and have your server match that IP address from step 2. If it's a match, voila, you know where they've come from!

Comment: I am not sure this would have accurate detection in the event someone takes my deeplink from Facebook and puts it on their random blog.